# Amazon MWS - Testing / Sandbox / Production

Tags: sql-server

I am currently developing an application which uses the Amazon MWS. To integrate the API's with my application, I need to carry out testing. Amazon advised that as they do not have a sandbox account that this testing needed to be completed on the production site. Have since been advised that my seller account has been closed due to poor performance (for not despatching the products to myself :-)) and that I will not be able to create another account. Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: And you choose to tag this question as `sql-server` because...?

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty much out of luck unless you can find a seller willing to let you work with their account. You are doing the work for someone is my guess, so they might let you test it on theirs. But unless you keep an account open and in good standing, you will loose it and Amazon is almost impossible to deal with on issues like this.